# why is there not a Runtime error when assigning Graphics reference to Graphics2D reference variable in paintComponent method?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I know that the assignment Below gives a Runtime error and i know why:

```
Sub sb = (Sub) new Super();

public class Super {
    //class  members
}



public class Sub extends Super{
     //class members
}
```

But why is there not a RuntimeError, when we override the `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of javax.swng.JPanel (after all `Graphics2D extends Graphics` ):

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
```

is it because g already has a `Graphics2D` reference in it?

Comment: Yes. It isn't an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't an error because,  as your say, `g` is really a `Graphics2D` object instantiated by system (keep in ming `Graphics2D` is a subclass of `Graphics`).

When you do:

```
Sub sb = (Sub) new Super();
```

you are explicity creating a new object of the superclass. However, when you do:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
```

you are not creating new Graphics2D object, but casting an existing object which is already a `Graphics2D` instance.

In the case of swing rendering, the object to perform graphics operations is a `Graphics2D` object, but `paintComponent()` receive a `Graphics` object for backward compatibility.

Comment: So as i said g has Graphics2D reference in it or in other words the argument which is passed to the paintComponent(Graphics g) is a Graphics2D object(upcasting).

Answer (score 0):

There is no runtime error because it's not the same to what you're doing in your method what happens here is more like this:

```
public void doSomethingWithSuper(Super superObj) {
    superObj.methodOfSuper();
}

public void doSomethinfWithSubThatCanResultInException(Super superObj) {
    Sub sub = (Sub) superObj;
    sub.methodOdSub();
}

Super subObj = new Sub();
Super superObj = new Super();

doSomethingWithSuper(subObj); //ok
doSomethingWithSuper(superObj); //ok

doSomethinfWithSubThatCanResultInException(subObj); // ok because the dynamic type of subObj is Sub therefore the cast is valid
doSomethinfWithSubThatCanResultInException(superObj); // exception because the dynamic type of superObj is super therefore the cast is not valid
```